# How to write XML with variying number of elements in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a problem and I posted a question about it, but I do not want to mix it up with too many questions, so I decided to ask a general one here:

I have an XSD that gives me XML examples like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MT_AnalyseQueueResponse_EXT xmlns="urn:com.xx.xx">
  <Res xmlns="">
    <Location No="No1" Testpoint="Testpoint1" />
    <Results>
      <Cylinder Date="Date1" BatchNo="BatchNo1" Result="Result1" Info="Info1" BID="BID1" Complete="Complete1" Release="Release1">
        <Detail Component="Component1" DeviceID="DeviceID1" Value="Value1" Info="Info1" Result="Result1" Unit="Unit1" Limit="Limit1" />
      </Cylinder>
      <Cylinder Date="Date1" BatchNo="BatchNo1" Result="Result1" Info="Info1" BID="BID1" Complete="Complete1" Release="Release1">
        <Detail Component="Component1" DeviceID="DeviceID1" Value="Value1" Info="Info1" Result="Result1" Unit="Unit1" Limit="Limit1" />
        <Detail Component="Component1" DeviceID="DeviceID1" Value="Value1" Info="Info1" Result="Result1" Unit="Unit1" Limit="Limit1" />
      </Cylinder>
     </Results>
  </Res>
</MT_AnalyseQueueResponse_EXT>
```

My problem is not that it doesn't have a fixed 1:1 relation. I have 1 Location with N Cylinders with M Details each. The N and M vary from case to case.

How do I fill/write them in VB if I need to do that during several "for" loops?

Comment: This may be caused with serialization. When you serialize an object, only a property without the "default value" would be serialized to xml. This would be assuming that the xml document was generated using  System.Xml.XmlSerializer. The xml file can also be deserialized using the same. If you use System.Xml.XmlSerializer to deserialize your file to an object, all the missing fields would then be filled with the default values.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you mean. I am not very familiar with XML, therefore I just rely on some things I read up and some examples I found and a lot trial and error. I know that is not the right way, but that is how it is. So, can you put that a bit more into examples? EDIT: I do not have a problem with any defauls, that XML up there is the example. I want to fill those attributes and elements and the problem is, I only manage to fill exactly one cylinder with one detail row and can not put it to use within my loop and actual code

Comment: Try looking at the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is at least the 3rd posting on this subject today.  I gave the solution this morning to use List(Of) to solve issue.